# Is it possible to use com.apple.CalendarAgent.plist to open a third-party Calendar app?

Tags: macos, calendar.app, launchctl, icalendar, things-for-mac

From what I understand, MacHD/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.CalendarAgent.plist handles calendar requests and opens them in the default MacOS calendar (calendar.app). I am wondering if it's possible to edit this file to have it open a third-party calendar instead, ie. (Fantastical 2).

Background: I am using Things 3 (to-do list app) and I've linked it with my calendar events. However, when I click on the linked events, it opens up in calendar.app, when I'd like to have it open in Fantastical 2.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that plist file factors into which calendar app gets launched (it seems like it more about setting about handling of detection of events and alarms), but you might have luck with the 3rd-party Preference Pane "RCDefaultApp", which can be configured to use a different default calendar app:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried changing some of the settings (removing all URLs, extensions and UTIs associated with calendar.app), but no luck. Is there anything else I could try, like removing the Calendar app altogether?

Comment: I wouldn't delete the built-in Calendar app without a system backup (and the time it might take to do a full restore).  Do some more searching.  I found this guide to associating .ics files with a different calendar app (https://support.busymac.com/help/71161-how-to-set-busycal-and-busycontacts-as-the-default-apps).  It's not quite what you're trying to do, but maybe it helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I'm not sure what else to try. I've contacted the Things 3 team, and they said:
"At this moment we don't have a way to tell OS to invoke non-default calendar when you click an event - sorry!"
However, I thought (in this process) that I set Fantastical 2 as my default calendar app; I verified this in the 1st party Calendar app. Do you have any other ideas?